# Why doesn't srcset work properly with my flexbox?

Tags: html, css, srcset

I was trying to put 9 images with some text inside of a flexbox with three columns. I've succeded and it's working properly. Now, I'm trying to change some of them depending on their "visible" width. To my understanding, at certain browser width img1B should be changed either to img2B, or img3B. However, that doesn't happen. What's the reason for that? Does it have to do with resolution of my images?

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.img {
    max-width: 33%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="img">
            <img 
            src="../../Image base/1920x1080/img1B.jpg" 
            alt=""
            srcset="
            ../../Image base/1920x1080/img1B.jpg 400w,
            ../../Image base/1920x1080/img2B.jpg 600w,
            ../../Image base/1920x1080/img3B.jpg 800w
            "
            >
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the attribute `sizes` aswell to define a set of media conditions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes

The built-in media query functionality of the `img` element works like this:

- `srcset` sets different images with different sizes
- `sizes` sets the conditions for the browser to decide which image defined in `srcset` to display